# 301 Redirection from old archive link to new

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I changed my blog archive links from https://example.com/2019/09/ to https://example.com/blog/2019/09/. I would like to redirect from old url to new one. Is there any way to redirect all archive url along with /blog/ slug. Currently old urls goes to 404.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect "/NNNN/NN/" to "/blog/NNNN/NN/"
RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d\d/$ /blog/$0 [R=302,L]
```

The `$0` backreference contains the entire URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (1st argument).

Change the `302` (temporary) redirect to `301` (permanent) only once you have confirmed that it works as intended.

Assuming this is WordPress then you don't need to repeat the `RewriteEngine On` directive, since it probably already occurs later in the file.